# Nginx and mup, nginx is not working meteor

Tags: nginx, meteor, meteor-up

I deployed my app using mup

Code

```
{
  "servers": [
    {
      "host": "128.xxx.xxx.16",
      "username": "root",
      "pem": "~/.ssh/id_rsa"
    }
  ],

  "setupMongo": true,
  "setupNode": true,
  "nodeVersion": "0.10.36",
  "setupPhantom": true,
  "appName": "MyApp",
  "app": "/home/user/work/myapp/rewrite/cf/",
  "env": {
    "ROOT_URL": "http://myapp.com",
    "UPSTART_UID": "root",
  },
  "deployCheckWaitTime": 15
}
```

which is working fine, but now I want to install nginx in my server and installed it using `apt-get`

my nginx config

```
server {
        server_name www.myapp.com;
        return 301 $scheme://myapp.com$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name myapp.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

but this is not working when I go to my app with `www` and `non-www` both are taking to two different sessions,

I tried to stop meteor app using `stop myapp` and go to my website I'm getting the following error page
which is I think not related to nginx

[image]
<sub>(source: [meteor.com](https://forums.meteor.com/uploads/default/1996/aae0413b269ba1c7.png))</sub>

when I go to my server and type nginx status, it is running,

[image]
<sub>(source: [meteor.com](https://forums.meteor.com/uploads/default/1997/34180fec39428eea.png))</sub>

What is wrong with my nginx?Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

your mup.json file should look something like this, i guess

```
"env": {
    "PORT":3000,
    "ROOT_URL": "http://myapp.com",
    "UPSTART_UID": "root",
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try dumping mup altogether. For example, I couldnt get mup to work at all on ubuntu 14.

If you're looking to get meteor running you could try this tutorial. I had to completely uninstall mongodb and mup before getting it to run on nginx.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-meteor-js-application-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-nginx

Comment: Maybe you should try `mupx`.